# Android HELP ME, I have to get user's typing data from keypad using accessibilityService for disable people

Tags: android, keyboard, touch, accessibilityservice

I am developing the application for the disable person.

I want to make a app which can read typing data by user.

So, I use accessibiltyservice.

In that case,
how can I get the input value from user?

Please help me, insight me....

Answer (score 0):

Yout should use EditText view to read user input

Comment: I use accessibility for accessing other app. In many other app, there are a lot of place to put the data by keypad... So, in that case, User push the character on keypad, then, My program can read that input value.. how can I do it?